# Generating system activity reports

Tags: server, 16.04, cron, performance

I'm doing some performance monitoring of a server running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed the `sysstat` package with the intention of using `sar` to monitor system activity.

As I understand it when the package is installed there are 2 cron jobs set-up : one that runs the `sa1` command to collect and store the activity data, and the other that runs daily and executes the `sa2` command to generate a human-readable report from the (binary) activity data. These files are supposed to be written to the `/var/log/sysstat` directory.

From the `man` page:

> Standard system activity daily data files are located in the /var/log/sysstat directory by default.

But on my server `/var/log/sysstat` is a file **not** a directory (why?). I can tell by looking at the last modified time that the file is being updated regularly so it appears that the activity data is being logged.

Here's the content of the configuration file (`/etc/sysstat/sysstat`):

```
HISTORY=30
COMPRESSAFTER=10
SADC_OPTIONS="-S DISK"

# Directory where sa and sar files are saved.
SA_DIR=/var/log/sysstat

ZIP="xz"
#YESTERDAY=no

# By default sa2 script generates reports files (the so called sarDD files).
# Set this variable to false to disable reports generation.
#REPORTS=false
```

The problem I'm having is that the `sa2` reports aren't being generated. I've had it running for a while now and nothing.

What do I need to do to generate (and view) the activity reports?